# Why is Hibernate selecting 1:M as 1 query per row?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate in Spring Boot 3.2.2 and it seems like Hibernate is generating 1 query per row on a many-to-many table:

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "film_actor",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "film_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")})
  @Schema
  private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();
```

I ended up with 1000's of queries of:

```
2024-02-01T21:28:40.985579Z   118 Query select a1_0.film_id,a1_1.actor_id,a1_1.first_name,a1_1.last_name from film_actor a1_0 join actor a1_1 on a1_1.actor_id=a1_0.actor_id where a1_0.film_id=1000
```

Why isn't it doing just a single inner join query?

Instead it looks like its just query the first able first:

```
select f1_0.film_id,f1_0.description,f1_0.rating,f1_0.release_year,f1_0.title from film f1_0
```

And then requerying it with one join at a time.